# How to fire this not in type of query in elastic search with php?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Example - `Select * from table1 where id not in ('a','b','c')`.

I am using this:

```
$searchParams = array();
$searchParams['index'] = 'articles';
$searchParams['type']  = 'staging';
$searchParams['size']= $size;
$searchParams['body']['filter']['bool']['must_not']['term']['_id'] = $filter;
```

`$filter` variable has some ids in this form `['a','b','c']`

But it is not returning correct result.Any Suggestions ?

EDIT:-
I need to filter results based on _id column in elastic search

Comment: So how are you passing the params to your query.?

Comment: $params['hosts'] = array (
            '10.0.0.103:9200'         // IP + Port

        );
$this->client = new Elasticsearch\Client($params);
$retDoc = $this->client->search($searchParams)

Answer (score 1):

I think that it should be `terms` instead of `term`:

```
$searchParams['body']['filter']['bool']['must_not']['terms']['_id'] = $filter;
```

or

```
$searchParams['body']['filter']['bool']['must_not'][]['terms']['_id'] = $filter;
```

looking at [terms](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) and [bool queries](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_search_operations.html). But I'm not an expert in this.

Comment: The second option is the correct one.  The `must_not` accepts an array of objects, so in PHP you need to specify the empty array to create a new object inside of the `must_not`.  And you are correct, it needs to be `terms`